# Managing SVN Checkout for users that don't have access to externs

Tags: svn, authentication, svn-externals

I have a folder in one SVN repository (repo1) that has an extern to another SVN repository (repo2). I have a user that has access to repo1 but not repo2.

When that user tries to do the checkout they get an error message when checking out the external from repo2 and then the entire checkout fails.

Is it possible to complete the checkout by ignoring the external that it does not have access to?

I can provide more clarification if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the --ignore-externals option during checkout and update.